# Regex - замена значения SERVER_URI по шаблону

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Я не очень знаком с регулярными выражениями, погуглив, всё равно не нашел решения, поэтому, сама задача:

- Есть путь, к примеру: '**///page//xyz/qwe?abc**'.
- Нужно произвести *замену*, чтобы на выходе оставался только '**/page/xyz**', то есть, по шаблону ' **/1/2** '
- По моим предположениям, сделать это нужно при помощи *регулярных выражений* и *preg_replace*.

Буду рад любым предложениям!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть так *(если я правильно понял)*

```
$str = '///page//xyz/qwe?abc';
preg_match_all('~(?<=/)[^/]+(?=/)~', $str, $a);

echo '/'. join('/', $a[0]);
```

Comment: спасибо, частично, это правильно
Но помимо замены нескольких слэшей на один, мне нужно еще и отсекать текст после ' /page/xyz '

Comment: @Evgeniy ок, сейчас подправлю

Comment: я пытался обрезать всё после второго слэша (/page/xyz/←), но, опять же, знаний в рег.выраж. не хватает

Comment: @Evgeniy обновил ответ. Вариантов может быть довольно много.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё как нужно!